# Transparent PNG menu item backgrounds in IE6 with rollovers

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6, png, transparency

Hi I have been trying to do this for what feels like all my life

I have a list menu with block display links, each link has a sliding doors png background image. I have used this javascript (http://www.ideashower.com/our_solutions/png-hover/) to implement the alphaimageloader fix for ie6 using a transparent gif.

When I test it for the first time it works but if I click to a different page and then click back it doesn't work anymore - the menu completely disappears, I can get it to work again by duplicating the transparent gif and changing it's name, but again if I go to another page and then come back to it, it stops working and the menu dissappears.

Is this a server caching issue or something like that.

Any thoughts on this would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If its caching then maybe the AJAX trick could do.
Create random number each time the code is executed and add it to the transparent gif url.

so in file pngHover.js:

> transparentImage =
>   '/j/transparent.gif';

would be

> transparentImage = '/j/transparent.gif?143253214';

To get random number in js google it, it will give you plenty./